# Furnace won’t kick off once the desired temp is met

Tags: furnace

I had a Honeywell thermostat (older model), I replaced it with a new Honeywell basic model. Reason for replacing is because once I set the temp, and the temp was reached the furnace won’t kick off. The air from the vents will turn cool once the temp is reached, but continue to run. What’s my issue?

Comment: That sounds like a furnace problem, not a thermostat problem. The fan can usually be run in "Auto" or "On". If when things start and it is warm enough, the fan does **not** run, but only while the furnace is on and then after it stops producing heat, then the problem is somewhere in the fan control board, relays, etc. The furnace may be designed to continue running the fan until a particular sensor shows it is cool enough - if that sensor is not functioning properly then the fan will keep running. Model # of furnace may help with figuring this out.

Comment: What make and model is your furnace, and can you post a wiring diagram for the unit for that matter?

Comment: Does it work with the new thermostat?

Answer (score 0):

If your fan is not set to on your fan contactor has probably welded the contacts, many times a little thump will break it loose. The contactor is a relay designed for motor loads.
On many of the homes I have worked on I have added a fan on switch at the furnace is it possible you have one of these? The fan will run forever in either case and the thermostat cycles the gas valve on and off.